# MongoDB replace sub doc Id, with the document

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am sure it was answered before but I can't find any proper explanation, maybe the aggregate methods I assumed are not relevant here.
I have a mongo collection containing an array which points to sub-docs

```
{
  _id: '123',
  name: 'my shop',
  items: [
    {
      itemId: '234',
    },
    {
      itemId: '345',
    },
  ]
}
```

This is the collection of sub docs:

```
{
   _id: '234',
   name: 'apple',
   amount: 13
},
{
   _id: '345',
   name: 'orange',
   amount: 25
},
```

How can I replace in the upper document the id-reference to the actual document content.
Desired final result:

```
{
  _id: '123',
  name: 'my shop',
  items: [
    {
      itemId: '234',
      name: 'apple',
      amount: 13
    },
    {
      itemId: '345',
      name: 'orange',
      amount: 25
    },
  ]
}
```

Comment: Are you looking to do this on a single document of main collection or How big is your dataset if you're doing this on entire collection..

Comment: @whoami I am doing it on a single parent document which might have up to 30 sub-doc.

Comment: Ok in that case, check this :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60548338/mongodb-aggregation-double-lookup-and-merge-lookup-response-to-respective-obj/60550506#60550506, apart from double `$lookup` everything should be same !! Let me know if that helps, we can mark this as a duplicate :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say sample data for `shop` collection is:

```
{
  _id: '123',
  name: 'my shop',
  items: [
    {
      itemId: '234',
    },
    {
      itemId: '345',
    },
  ]
}
```

And the sample data for `item` collection is:

```
{
   _id: '234',
   name: 'apple',
   amount: 13
},
{
   _id: '345',
   name: 'orange',
   amount: 25
}
```

Then the aggregation will be like this one:

```
 db.shop.aggregate([{
    $lookup: { 
        from: 'item',
        localField: 'items.itemId', 
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'items'
   }
}])
```